# How to perform Earth Mover's Distance instead of DoG for center surround difference on multiscale level in images in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision

I am working on a image processing project where i have to perform center surround difference calculation with Earth Mover's distance(EMD) on multiscale level but the problem is that i can't figure it out how center surround difference works and how could i use EMD for it.

I found the python function for EMD but it works with 2 source image histograms whereas in my problem i have only one source.
I am generating multi scales of the image using skimage's pyramid_gaussian function using solution provided on 
link: https://gist.github.com/duhaime/211365edaddf7ff89c0a36d9f3f7956c

I tried:

```
def get_img(path, norm_size=True, norm_exposure=False):
    img = imread(path, flatten=True).astype(int)
    if norm_size:
        img = resize(img, (height, width), anti_aliasing=True, preserve_range=True)
    if norm_exposure:
        img = normalize_exposure(img)
    return img

def get_histogram(img):
    h, w = img.shape
    hist = [0.0] * 256
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            hist[img[i, j]] += 1
    return np.array(hist) / (h * w) 

def normalize_exposure(img):
    img = img.astype(int)
    hist = get_histogram(img)
    cdf = np.array([sum(hist[:i+1]) for i in range(len(hist))]) # get the sum of vals accumulated by each position in hist
    sk = np.uint8(255 * cdf)        # determine the normalization values for each unit of the cdf
    height, width = img.shape   # normalize each position in the output image
    normalized = np.zeros_like(img)
    for i in range(0, height):
        for j in range(0, width):
            normalized[i, j] = sk[img[i, j]]
    return normalized.astype(int)

def earth_movers_distance(path_a, path_b):
    img_a = get_img(path_a, norm_exposure=True)
    img_b = get_img(path_b, norm_exposure=True)
    hist_a = get_histogram(img_a)
    hist_b = get_histogram(img_b)
    return wasserstein_distance(hist_a, hist_b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image = cv2.imread("images/test3.jpg")
    pyramidlist=[]
    dst = []
    for (i, resized) in enumerate(pyramid_gaussian(image, downscale=1.4)):
        if resized.shape[0] < 30 or resized.shape[1] < 30:
            break
        cv2.imshow(f"Layer {i+1}", resized)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        pyramidlist.append(resized[i])
    print(pyramidlist)
    print(len(pyramidlist)) 


cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but don't know how to use EMD after generating pyramids and calculate center surround difference.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please can you try and include a minimal code example within your question, rather than via outlink?

Comment: @pete23 hii, i have added the code where i am generating gaussian pyramids of the image and saving them in a list.

Comment: EMD computes a distance between two histograms. All distances are defined based on two points, you cannot compute a distance if you have only one point. Is your code meant to compare two levels of the pyramid?

Comment: @CrisLuengo yes cris, basically i want to calculate center-surround difference based on pyramid levels with EMD instead of using DoG as EMD computation is faster than DoG.